# How can I clear previous activity which is open from the tap on notification in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

There is a Reminder application. Now users created 5 Reminders. R1, R2, R3, R4, R5.

And for all reminders time is same. So all reminders came in same time. Now I tap on notification which is R1. and when I tap, it opens a particular activity and show according to details because I sent Id of that reminder in intent.

Now I click on R2/R3/R4/R5, it is opening details according to R1 only instead of  R2/R3/R4/R5.

Note: In **onReceive**, I create notification from that. Also, for all reminders, I open same activity, but details on that activity should be different according to Reminder ID. Also, when I send ReminderId/mReceivedId in intent, **it is correct**, not the same.

Code:

```
editIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderDetailActivity.class);
editIntent.putExtra(REMINDER_ID, mReceivedId);
editIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
editIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
editIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, rowId, editIntent, 0);
```

Complete code (I call createNotification() from onReceive):

```
private void createNotification() {
    int rowId = getRowId(mReceivedId);
    Uri mUri;
    if (preferenceManager.getRingtoneUri() != null) {
        mUri = Uri.parse(preferenceManager.getRingtoneUri());
    } else {
        mUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    String mTitle = reminder.getTitle();
    String id = "1";
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    if (mNotificationManager == null) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    Intent editIntent;
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
        if (mChannel == null) {
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, mTitle, importance);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, id);
        editIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderDetailActivity.class);
        editIntent.putExtra(REMINDER_ID, mReceivedId);
        editIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        editIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        editIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, rowId, editIntent, 0);
        builder.setContentTitle(mTitle)

                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentTitle(mTitle)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_black_24dp)
                .setSound(mUri)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText("Have you completed your task?"))
                .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_LARGE)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_icon_alarm, context.getString(R.string.pay_now), pendingIntent);
        builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));


    } else {
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, id);
        editIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderDetailActivity.class);
        editIntent.putExtra(REMINDER_ID, mReceivedId);
        editIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        editIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        editIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, rowId, editIntent, 0);
        builder.setContentTitle(mTitle)

                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentTitle(mTitle)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_black_24dp)
                .setSound(mUri)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_icon_alarm, context.getString(R.string.pay_now), pendingIntent)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText("Have you completed your task?"))
                .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_LARGE)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
    }

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    mNotificationManager.notify(rowId, notification);
}
```

Comment: can you show me the code where you are dealing with these extras?

Comment: are you finish activity before call and intent another one?

Comment: @Piyush this is not fro pending intent to set alarm, this is just only for create notification

Comment: @PoojaSingh But u want to clear previous activity if u start from notification na? Change _pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, rowId, editIntent, 0);_ to  _pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, rowId, editIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);_

Comment: @JawadMalik Notifications are created correct, there is no dobut, because I set title name and that is exact.

Comment: @alirezadaryani From where should I finish?

Comment: @Piyush but how?

Comment: @PoojaSingh Comment edited

Comment: @Piyush what I'm saying is, my notification are built perfectly. but when I tap on that, that time only it is showing previous details, which are already opened through previous notification

Comment: @Piyush onNewIntent means? where?

Comment: @PoojaSingh In your _ReminderDetailActivity_. This is override method

Comment: @Piyush while setting the alarm in AlarmManger, I'm using that flag only:  mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, rowId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: can you try logging the values you are getting in the intent extra after clicking on the notification?
You might get a clue there what is going wrong.

Comment: @Piyush Morning dear

Comment: @Piyush yr, can you solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58504998/error-code-100-while-working-with-in-app-update-followed-by-documentation-not

Comment: @Piyush this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517654/how-to-solve-install-status-code-100-while-working-with-in-app-update-in-androi

Answer (score -2):

Welcome to code party

As i seen, u want start an activity when another is already opened and it can’t get other extras.

So you must before sending another intent, clear bundle or finish activity.

Edited:

use this in your activity

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(final Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    this.setIntent(intent); //just add this line when overrided
}
```

do it and update me

Comment: That other activity is same, I'm not opening different different activities based on reminder Id. Please post code. And from where should I finish activity?

Comment: where you get extras?

Comment: public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mReceivedId = intent.getLongExtra(REMINDER_ID, 0);

Comment: from onReceive intent

Comment: over ride onNewIntent and use this code on it and say me what happen

Comment: what should I write i nside onNewIntent?